# Force headers on all Rails 404/500 responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set the 'X-Frame-Options' header on all responses returned by my Rails application. It seems like this header is *not* set on 404 or 500 type responses. How can I configure Rails to **always** include this header?

It appears I somehow need to hook into Rails to ensure these headers are always set.

Answer (score 0):

I am having success using the below middleware as my 'exceptions_app'.

```rb
class XSecurityHandler
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    _status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
    headers['X-Frame-Options'] = "SAMEORIGIN"
    headers['X-Content-Type-Options'] = "nosniff"
    [status(env), headers, response]
  end

  private
  def status(env)
    path = env["ORIGINAL_FULLPATH"]
    if path == "/404"
      404
    elsif path == "/422"
      422
    else
      500
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Set default headers in **config/application.rb**:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

but it wont work, if you have configured reverse proxy (like nginx) to serve static assets which does not exists (404), but i think you know about this :)

Comment: Sorry, that won't work. The X-Frame-Options header appears to be scrubbed from 404s and 503s. I updated my question to reflect this.